# Several matrix operations in one single cell

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have this sample matrix where the rows refer to different species and the columns refer to different observed locations. The cells are filled with 1's or 0's depending if the species has been observed in that particular location (i.e: species B has been observed in location #1 and #2)

```
        1       2       3
a       1       1       0
b       1       1       0
c       1       0       0
d       0       0       1
```

I have to calculate the occurrence of each species. The occurrence of a species is defined as: "the number of other species in which a certain species has been observed divided by the total number of other species" (i.e: species A has been observed with species B and C in location #1 and species B in location #2, thus the occurrence is 2 species out of 3 (B and C out of {B,C,D} or 0.667).
An occurrence of 1 means that the species X has been found with all the other species and an occurrence of 0 means that the species X has been always found alone.

The result would be something like:

species occurrence
a   0.67
b   0.67
c   0.67
d   0.00

I am able to generate a helper matrix with as many rows and columns as there are species and using SUMPRODUCT check for each interaction if it does happen or not. Then sum up all the column values and divide and get the occurrence.

My question is: "**It is possible to perform such a formula in one single cell?**"

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that table is in `A1:D5`, in `E2`, **array formula****:

`=MAX(0,SUM(N(MMULT(B$2:D$5,TRANSPOSE(B2:D2))>0))-1)/(COUNTA(A$2:A$5)-1)`

Copy down as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Excellent - I would have got there eventually but not as concisely

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks!